# How can I get the search result count for a dynamic drop down list?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a count problem in PHP...

I am creating a drop down list dynamically from MySQL. When I select the first drop down menu, how can I get the search result count... like 10 products from the database?

Here is my code:

ajax..file:

```
var xmlHttp

function showCount(str)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
 {
 alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
 return;
 }
var url="phpApplication.php";
url=url+"?action=count2";
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("countR").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
 {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
 xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
 {
 // Internet Explorer
 try
   {
   xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }
 catch (e)
   {
   xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

PHP Application:

```
class Application {


     public function __construct () { 

    } 


    function conn($sql)
{   

      $host      = "localhost";
      $username  = "root";
      $pwd       = "";
      $dbname    = "example";

    //echo "commnecing connection to local db<br>"
    if (!($conn=mysql_connect($host, $username, $pwd)))  {
        printf("error connecting to DB by user = $username and pwd=$pwd");
        exit;
    }
    $db3=mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die("Unable to connect to local database");


    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Can't connect because ". mysql_error());

    return $result;

}//end function  


function dropdown($field, $table)
{ 
  //initialize variables
  $oHTML  = '';
  $result = '';

  //check to see if the field is passed correctly
  if (($field == "")||($table == ""))
  {
    die("No column or table specified to create drop down from!");
  }

  $sql = "select distinct($field) from $table";

  //call the db function and run the query
  $result = $this->conn($sql);

  //if no results are found to create a drop down return a textbox
  if ((!$result) ||(mysql_num_rows($result)==0))
  {
    $oHTML .= "<input type='text' name='$field' value='' size='15'>";
  }elseif (($result)&&(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)){


    //build the select box out of the results
    $oHTML .= "<select name='$field' onchange='showCount(this.value)'>\n<option value='all'>All</option>\n";
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $oHTML .= "<option value='".$rows[$field]."'>".$rows[$field]."</option>\n";

    }
    $oHTML .= "</select>\n";

  }
  //send the value back to the calling code
  return $oHTML;
}//end function


function countResult(){

  $sql2 = "select * from produkt_finder_table where 1 ";


  if ( $q == (!empty($_POST['Bauform_d']))&&($_POST['Bauform_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql2 .= " and Bauform_d like '". addslashes($_POST['Bauform_d'])."%' ";
  }


  if ((!empty($_POST['Beschreibung_d']))&&($_POST['Beschreibung_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql2 .= " and Beschreibung_d like '". addslashes($_POST['Beschreibung_d'])."%' ";
  }


   if ((!empty($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d']))&&($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql2 .= " and SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d like '". addslashes($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d'])."%' ";
  }


   if ((!empty($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d']))&&($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql2 .= " and SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d like '". addslashes($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d'])."%' ";
  }


   if ((!empty($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d']))&&($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql2 .= " and ArtikelProduktgruppe_d like '". addslashes($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d'])."%' ";
  }



$result2 = $this->conn($sql2);
  //run query

  if (!$result2){ die("No results due to database error.<br>".mysql_error());  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($result2)==0)
  {
    echo "0";
  }else{

    echo mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
}



function count1(){

   if ((!empty($_POST['Bauform_d']))&&($_POST['Bauform_d'] != 'all')) {


}

    $sql2 .= " and Bauform_d like '". addslashes($_POST['Bauform_d'])."%' ";
     $sql2 = "select * from produkt_finder_table where 1 ";
     $result2 = $this->conn($sql2);
      if (!$result2){ die("No results due to database error.<br>".mysql_error());  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($result2)==0)
  {
    echo "0";
  }else{

    echo mysql_num_rows($result2);
  }


  //run query



}



function countResultAll(){

 $sql = "select * from produkt_finder_table where 1 ";



  if ((!empty($_POST['searchfield']))&&($_POST['searchfield'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and ArtikelName like '". addslashes($_POST['searchfield'])."%' ";
  }

$result = $this->conn($sql);
  //run query

  if (!$result){ die("No results due to database error.<br>".mysql_error());  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
  {
    echo "0";
  }else{

    echo mysql_num_rows($result);
}
}



function search()
{

//base sql
  $sql = "select * from produkt_finder_table where 1 ";

//get the values from the form


  if ((!empty($_POST['Bauform_d']))&&($_POST['Bauform_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and Bauform_d like '". addslashes($_POST['Bauform_d'])."%' ";
  }

  if ((!empty($_POST['Beschreibung_d']))&&($_POST['Beschreibung_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and Beschreibung_d like '". addslashes($_POST['Beschreibung_d'])."%' ";
  }

   if ((!empty($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d']))&&($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d like '". addslashes($_POST['SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d'])."%' ";
  }

   if ((!empty($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d']))&&($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d like '". addslashes($_POST['SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d'])."%' ";
  }

   if ((!empty($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d']))&&($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and ArtikelProduktgruppe_d like '". addslashes($_POST['ArtikelProduktgruppe_d'])."%' ";
  }


 //run query
  $result = $this->conn($sql);

  if (!$result){ die("No results due to database error.<br>".mysql_error());  }


  if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
  {
    echo "No Results found!";
  }else{


     echo "<table border='1' class='corner'><th width='332'><a href='product.php'>Back</a></th>";
     echo "<th>Product Result</th>";
     echo "<td width='40' align='center' style=' font-size:16px'><div id='countR'>";
     $this->countResult();
     echo "</div></td>";
        echo "</table>";

    // echo '<div style="float:right; font-size:16px">'.$this->countResultAll().'</div>';
    // echo "<div style='float:left; font-size:16px'>Produkt Result</div>";

    echo "<table border='1' class='corner'>"; 

     $i = 1;
    if((mysql_num_rows($result) % 2) == 0){
    $complete = false;
     }else{
    $complete = true;
     }

    while ($rows= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

      echo "<td>";
      echo "<ul><li class='addResult'><span class='red'>".$rows['Bauform_d']."<br /><span class='black'>".$rows['ArtikelName']."</span></span><img src='{imag}' alt='' /> <a href='#'>More Info</a> </li></ul>";
      echo "</td>";

   if(($i % 2) == 0){

       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }   

      $i++;
}
if($complete == true){

    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

}     


    echo "</tr></table>";
      echo "<table border='1' class='corner'><th width='332'><a href='product.php'>Back</a> <div></div></th>";
     echo "<th>Product Result</th>";
     echo "<td width='40' align='center' style=' font-size:16px'>";
     $this->countResult();
     echo "</td>";
        echo "</table>";

}
}


function show_form()
{

  $Bauform   = $this->dropdown('Bauform_d','produkt_finder_table');
  $Beschreibung  = $this->dropdown('ArtikelGruppe_d','produkt_finder_table');
   $SelectSchutzart  = $this->dropdown('SelectSchutzart_Cust_Bereich_d','produkt_finder_table');
    $SelectErfassungswinkel  = $this->dropdown('SelectErfassungswinkel_Cust_Bereich_d','produkt_finder_table');
     $ArtikelProduktgruppe  = $this->dropdown('ArtikelProduktgruppe_d','produkt_finder_table');

  echo "<form name='search' action='productResult.php?action=search' method='POST'>
        <table width='50%' align='center' valign='center' class='corner'>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='2' align='center'> Search Form  <div id='countR' style='float:right; font-size:16px'>Count</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align='right'>Montageart:</td><td>$Bauform</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align='right'>ProduktGruppe:</td><td>$Beschreibung</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align='right'>Speisung:</td><td>$SelectSchutzart</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align='right'>Reichweite:</td><td> $SelectErfassungswinkel </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align='right'>Erfwinkel:</td><td>$ArtikelProduktgruppe </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Go!'></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";

}//end function




function searchAll()
{

//base sql
  $sql = "select * from produkt_finder_table where 1 ";

//get the values from the form
//NOTE: You should do way more valdation on the values before you attempt to process anything


  if ((!empty($_POST['searchfield']))&&($_POST['searchfield'] != 'all'))
  {
    $sql .= " and ArtikelName like '". addslashes($_POST['searchfield'])."%' ";
  }

  //run query
  $result = $this->conn($sql);

  if (!$result){ die("No results due to database error.<br>".mysql_error());  }


  if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
  {
    echo "No Results found!";
  }else{


     echo "<table border='1' class='corner'><th width='332'><a href='product.php'>Back</a></th>";
     echo "<th>Product Result</th>";
     echo "<td width='40' align='center' style=' font-size:16px'><div id='countR'>";
     $this->countResultAll();
     echo "</div></td>";
     echo "</table>";

    // echo '<div style="float:right; font-size:16px">'.$this->countResultAll().'</div>';
    // echo "<div style='float:left; font-size:16px'>Produkt Result</div>";

    echo "<table border='1' class='corner'>"; 

     $i = 1;
    if((mysql_num_rows($result) % 2) == 0){
    $complete = false;
     }else{
    $complete = true;
     }

    while ($rows= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

      echo "<td>";
      echo "<ul><li class='addResult'><span class='red'>".$rows['Bauform_d']."<br /><span class='black'>".$rows['ArtikelName']."</span></span><img src='{imag}' alt='' /> <a href='#'>More Info</a> </li></ul>";
      echo "</td>";

   if(($i % 2) == 0){

       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }   

      $i++;
}
if($complete == true){

    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

}     
     echo "</tr></table>";
     echo "<table border='1' class='corner'><th width='332'><a href='product.php'>Back</a> <div></div></th>";
     echo "<th>Product Result</th>";
     echo "<td width='40' align='center' style=' font-size:16px'>";
     $this->countResultAll();
     echo "</td>";
     echo "</table>";

}
}
}

$action = $_GET['action'];

$proFin = new Application();

switch($action) {

        case 'show':
            $proFin->show_form();
        break;

        case 'search':
            $proFin->search();
        break; 

        case 'searchAll':
            $proFin->searchAll();
        break; 

        case 'count':
            $proFin->countResult();
        break; 

        case 'count1':
            print 'hallo';
        break; 

        case 'count2':

            if (!empty($_POST))
{


        var_dump($_POST);
}


        break; 

        case 'count3':
            echo $rows[$field];
        break; 
        }
```

Comment: there should be an HTML file where the AJAX is also included, please post.

Comment: See, the HTML defines the DOM object to change by the ID in this case countR, the XML response to the AJAX function is coming from PHP, which means it has to contain a countR tag, wrapping the replacement info.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on apache with firefox and "empty" is replaced with "23".

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test ajax</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
var xmlHttp

function showCount(str)
{
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }
    var url="testajax.php";
    url=url+"?action=count2";
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("countR").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
</script>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#0000FF" vlink="#000080" alink="#FF0000" onload="showCount( 'heelo' )" >
<span id="countR">empty</span>
</body>
</html>
```

testajax.php

```
<?

if( $_REQUEST[ 'action' ] == 'count2' )
{
    header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
    echo <<<XMLTOP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

XMLTOP;
        echo( '<countr>23</countr>' );
}
?>
```

// for the mysql row counting in mysql use
You could use this to get the count and put as the first row.

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...";

$result = mysql_query( $query ) or LogFatalError( "Database error: " . mysql_error() );
$count  = mysql_result( mysql_query( 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' ), 0, 0 );
```

Comment: thanks for ur nice and cool example, i mean i post the real php class i am using could u some how, look at it and tell me what is going wrong..
thanks agian.

Comment: add 

        header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

before

switch( $action )